# NodeJS/AngularJS unable to display information on Webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bash, ubuntu

I am following *NodeJS* and *AngularJS* *(v 1.2.x)* app [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7F1nLajs4Eo) via *Bash on Ubuntu on Windows*.

**Issues:**

> 1. Log "I received the data I requested" not displayed in Ubuntu bash shell
> 2. Information not displayed on webpage

**Results and code:**

---

**Ubuntu Shell Result:**

[image: Ubuntu Shell Result]

---

**Webpage**

[image: Result]

---

**Controller.js**

[image: Controller.js]

---

**Server.js**

[image: Server.js]

---

**Index.js**

[image: Index.js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space in your `tr`

Change it to `<tr ng-repeat "contact in contactlist">`

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra space in Index.html, `ng-repeat="contact in contact list"`
It should be `ng-repeat="contact in contactlist"`